# Intercepting singleton instances

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm receiving "Potential Lifestyle Mismatches"

> Component 'MyComponent' with lifestyle Singleton depends on
>   'Castle.TypedFactory.Interceptor' with lifestyle Transient

Is there any issue using an Interceptor against multiples singletone instances?

```
,Component.For<ApiInterceptor>()

, AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<MyServiceContract>()
    .Where(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs<MyServiceContract>())
    .Configure(c => c.Interceptors(typeof(ApiInterceptor)))
    .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Singleton)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably fine. There's a reason why this diagnostics is called *potential* lifestyle mismatches.

Comment: I assume reason of the message is due to "Castle.TypedFactory.Interceptor" lifestyle set by TypedFactory Facilty to Transient. My guess is that lifestyle has been choosen to fit all situations. Am I right?

Comment: yes, the interceptor is transient to give it the most flexibility.